# python logging multiple calls after each instantiation

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I have multiple modules and they each have their own log. The all write to the log correctly however when a class is instantiated more than once the log will write the same line multiple times depending on the number of times it was created. 
If I create the object twice it will log every messages twice, create the object three times it will log every message three times, etc...

I was wondering how I could fix this without having to only create each object only once.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the handler multiple times after each instantiation of a log. I checked if the handler had already been added at the instantiation and that fixed the multiple writes.